# Создание SOCKS прокси с помощью SSH соединения к удаленному Linux серверу

Tags: ssh, socks5, ssh-tunnel

Для семестральной работы нужно протестировать SSH туннелирование, с локальным и обратным разобралась. С динамическим проблема.

В качестве удаленного сервера использую Linux Centos 7 by https://linuxzoo.net/. Мой компьютер на Windows 10, так что для создания туннеля использую PuTTY (хотя пробовала и через команду ssh в PowerShell). Прокси настраивала для Firefox 71.0

Делала по туториалам: [вот этот](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel) и [этот](https://romantelychko.com/blog/1058/)

Через PuTTY создавала динамический туннель и подключалась к машине. Firefox настраивала согласно туториалам. И как бы все должно работать, но нет, страницы не грузятся долго и происходит истечение времени ожидания.

Я предполагаю, что проблема в сервере. Возможно ли, что его админы блокируют такое? Буду благодарна принять отличные и не очень идеи для решения моей проблемы. И если у кого то, есть предложения как показать функционал динамического туннелирования SSH то welcome.

Comment: Попробуйте зайти на удаленную машину по ssh и с нее дернуть wget'ом какой-нить сайт, типа 
wget lib.ru - чтобы убедиться, что прокси-машина в состоянии лазать в интернетик

Comment: Спасибо! Проверила, доступ ограничен, wget возвращает 403 Forbidden. Не нашла у linuxzoo возможность получить доступ к интернету. Поищу другой сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В такой ситуации неплохо было бы для начала проверить, а доступен ли интернет с той машины, через которую вы хотите проксировать. Сделать это можно при помощи, например `wget`:

```
wget ya.ru
```

И посмотреть на вывод. Если там пришел ответ `200` и правдоподобный контент - дело не в бобине, ищите ошибку в конфигурации тоннеля.